# Promote People Picker from Infopath to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, workflow, infopath, people-picker

I wanted to promote a people picker field in my Infopath form to Sharepoint column. I know that we couldn't promote people picker(group) to SP as people/group column. So, I only promote the Person:DisplayName to SP. I had searched and I found that we could add people/group in SP by using a workflow with AccountID or DisplayName. But I couldn't found how to do it. I already tried this [solution](http://sharepointblank.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/promoting-people-picker-field-from-infopath/), but because of my lack of knowledge at SP and Infopath, it didn't work. Could anyone tell me the steps or maybe give me a better solution. Please, help me.
Thank you very much

Comment: You can promote a people picker with values as Display Name, Account ID and Account Type.

Comment: I want to promote people picker as people/group column. I already did that. I promoted my people picker as Display Name (Single line of text).

Comment: Create a new person Column in the library, and promote the display name and account id. And then create a work for an item creation and updation, In this workflow you take the value of the account id and copy that to the person column, you need to take the account id because if you take the display name and names of some employees are common it will not validate and resolve and gives error on the Workflow.